# Travel to Europe without visa but with a Canadian refugee document?

Tags: canada, eu, visa-free-entry, refugees

I am a holder of Canadian travel document which is issued to Refugees and Stateless people. I am a refugee in Canada and cannot obtain my national passport which is Turkish. Can I travel to Europe without a visa?

Comment: You'll need a refugee travel document, but whether you need a visa or not depends entirely on which country or country you wish to visit. Germany [does not require a visa](http://www.canada.diplo.de/Vertretung/kanada/en/02/visa/blue__travel__document.html) for holders of a blue Canadian Travel Document for short stays for business or tourism, while [Switzerland does](https://www.sem.admin.ch/dam/data/sem/rechtsgrundlagen/weisungen/visa/bfm/bfm-anh01-liste2-e.pdf). So where do you plan to go?

Comment: "Europe" has a lot of countries. Perhaps restrict the question to the Schengen area?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, according to the [Government of Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=610&top=11).

> **I am a refugee and I need to travel outside Canada. What documents do I need to travel?**
>
> You need to get a [Refugee Travel Document](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#refugee_travel_document) from [Passport Canada](http://www.ppt.gc.ca/info/form.aspx?lang=eng&region=NonCA). It is recognized in all countries as a valid travel document. However, you cannot use it to travel to the country that you are a citizen of or the country of claimed persecution.
>
> If you are a:
>
> - [Convention refugee](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#convention_refugee), or
> - person in need of protection,
>
> you will need a Refugee Travel Document.
>
> To apply, you will need to give Passport Canada proof of your status in Canada. You will need either:
>
> - a letter from the Immigration and Refugee Board (IRB);
> - a confirmation of permanent residence; or
> - a [Verification of Status (VOS) document](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/glossary.asp#verification_of_status_document).
>
> If you are a Convention refugee, you should have a letter from the IRB. If you need to replace a lost letter, please [contact the IRB](http://www.irb-cisr.gc.ca/Eng/Contact/Pages/index.aspx).
>
> If you are a protected person who was selected overseas and resettled as a refugee in Canada, you should have either a Confirmation of Permanent Residence document, or a Permanent Resident Card. If you need to replace an expired, lost or stolen Permanent Resident Card, you can [apply for a new one](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/pr-card/index.asp).
>
> If you are a protected person with a positive Pre-Removal Risk Assessment (PRRA) decision, you should have a VOS. If your PRRA result was before December 17, 2012, and you did not get a VOS, or if you lost it, you can [apply for a new one](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/certcopy.asp).

[The Refugee Travel Document](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Refugee_travel_document) serves serves in lieu of a passport, allowing you to exit and return to Canada, which issued yours. Also known as a [Convention 1951 document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Refugees), those states (countries) who signed the agreement do recognize the document. Even so, you may still need to meet the regular requirements for a visa that nationals of your country of origin do, or any additional requirements that the destination country may impose on those with refugee status.

For that reason, check with country you wish to visit, through its embassy or consulate in Canada, to make sure of what governs your situation and whether you may need to apply for a visa.

Comment: Where does that say the refugee can travel without a visa?  And doesn't the "without a visa" part depend on the country being travelled to accepting the "country of residence" rather than "country of nationality" of the traveller?

Comment: Sorry, that sounded a little harsh, its not meant to be, just a couple of queries :)

Comment: @Moo no problem, and you're right; I need to add the EU bit, don't I, one that says refugees can enter on a Convention document w/o visa (or one that says you need a visa and your Convention doc accepted in lieu of passport. Thanks.

Comment: @Dorothy unfortunately, the Schengen area doesn't have a unified policy on this, as Zach Lipton noted in [his comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99508/travel-to-europe-without-visa-but-with-a-refugee-document#comment239312_99508).  This can make it complicated for those who want to go to multiple Schengen destinations.